# Reporte en Blanco...error en tomcat

Tags: genexus

tengo un sistema que genera reportes, los hace bien pero cada tanto los genera en blanco. Lo estoy solucionando reiniciando la instancia de la aplicación en el tomcat. Trabajo con Genexus16 Upgrade 6, java, tomcat.

Vimos que hay un error recurente en el log:

**org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() para servlet [confirmacion] lanzó excepción
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call reset() after response has been committed**

tienen idea que puede ser?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Moira,

Eso es un error "genérico" de manejo del socket http en el cual se llamó al reset después que la respuesta fue "comiteada".
Está enmascarando algún otro error.
El stacktrace completo puede aportar más información del problema.

Nota: En un caso me pasó algo similar y era la "heap memory" asignada al Java, en mi caso aumentándola resolvió el problema. De pronto aporta en tu caso.

Gustavo